# Get MAX value if column has a certain format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table similar to this:

`Example` table:

```
ID Column
---------------
xxx1234
xxx12345
xxx123456
20150001
```

I am trying to get a conditional MAX value depending on the value of the column based on whether it meets as certain format. Using the above example, the fourth record, 20150001, represents a "good record" because it contains the current year, and the start of an increment. So, in my table, records that are considered "good" (those subject to the query I am trying to write) have the format "year + increment". The first three, that do not follow this format, should not be conditioned to the query since they don't match this format and should not be subject when computing the max value. Those are bad records. In the above example, the expected result would be "20150002".

The MAX query is simple enough to write, however I am wondering about an approach where I can sanitize the query to only include those records whom meet the particular format, and increment the last four digits (0001 to 0002).

TIA!

Comment: Will it be always `xx..` or some other characters will be there

Comment: All numerics are "good"? select MAX(CONVERT(INT,ID))+1 from myTable where ISNUMERIC(ID) <> 1

Comment: other characters will be there.

Comment: @ mxix I will test right now

Comment: @mxix it returns "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xxxx' to data type int."

Comment: What should be the result when there is another row `20150007`

Comment: Both of the below approaches work great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isdate` function to filter out `ID Column`s that do not start with a valid year, and `isnumeric` to make sure the last 4 characters of the `ID Column` are valid increments. You also want the `len` to be 8, given this criteria. You can accomplish all this in the `where` clause:

```
-- load test data
declare @Example_Table table(ID_Column varchar(10))
insert into @Example_Table values
    ('xxx1234'),
    ('xxx12345'),
    ('xxx123456'),
    ('20150001')

-- return max valid ID_Column
select max(ID_Column) as max_ID_Column
from @Example_Table
where isdate(left(ID_Column,4)) = 1
    and isnumeric(right(ID_Column,4)) = 1
    and len(ID_Column) = 8

-- increment max valid ID_Column
update @Example_Table
set ID_Column = cast(ID_Column as int) + 1
where isdate(left(ID_Column,4)) = 1
    and isnumeric(right(ID_Column,4)) = 1
    and len(ID_Column) = 8

select * from @Example_Table

ID_Column
----------
xxx1234
xxx12345
xxx123456
20150002
```

Comment: Will this work for when the increment gets to 005, 006, and so on?

Comment: IsNumeric will include symbols '.' and '-', try '2015.0001' and '-2015.0001'.

Comment: @jtimperley, both of those will fail to meet the where criteria.

Comment: Yes, this will continue to increment to YYYY9999. After that, it will increment the year, which is a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to verify a correct year.  The second half of the regular expression I taylored to your examples of 0001 and 0002, this could be opened up by adding '[0-9]' for each digit you're expecting.

```
DECLARE @Sample VARCHAR(30) = '20150001';

SELECT CASE WHEN (@Sample LIKE '[12][09][0-9][0-9]000[12]') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END;

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@Sample, 1, 4),
    SUBSTRING(@Sample, 5, 4),
    CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(@Sample, 1, 4) LIKE '[12][09][0-9]') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
    CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(@Sample, 5, 4) LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END;
```